# How to get the excel sheet each row and column value

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have the excel file the code works fine, but how can I get each column and row value differently so that I can store the value in database. Thank you in advance

```
public class excel_demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\ExcelDemosWithPOI\\howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx"));

        //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        //Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            //For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                      System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");                            
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                       System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        file.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean each column and row value differently?

Comment: Do you mean you want to fetch by row+cell, not just iterate? If so, did you [try looking at the Apache POI documentation on fetching cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Comment: Yes I want to fetch each row+cell as i want to store the value in database.

Comment: Isn't your code already reading each row and cell?

Answer (score 0):

download [JEXCEL](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) api,and use this code,

```
import jxl.*;//import jxl package.


File excelSheet = null;
Workbook workbook = null;
Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(destFile));//destFile is excel file
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetNo);
columns = sheet.getColumns();
rows = sheet.getRows();
for(int row = 0;row <rows;row++)
{
   for(int col =0;col <columns;col++)
   {
      a[row][col] =Integer.parseInt( sheet.getCell(col,row).getContents());
   }
}
```

Hope this helps..